# How to construct long queries using rdf4j

Tags: sparql, rdf4j

I am trying to construct a long query using the rdf4j library and would like to use the count function that is available with SPARQL.

The original SPARQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?letter) AS ?count) WHERE { \
    ?letter a :Letter . \
    ?letter :writtenBy :John . \
    ?letter :writtenOn ?date . \
    FILTER(?date > NOW() && }
```

This is what I have so far using the rdf4j library

```
GraphPattern longPattern = GraphPatterns.tp(letter, ex.iri("a"), ex.iri("Letter")).
                and(GraphPatterns.tp(letter, ex.iri("writtenBy"), ex.iri("John"))).
                and(GraphPatterns.tp(letter, ex.iri("writtenOn"), date));
```

How can I implement the Count and use the NOW() functionality of sparql? I know there is a filter method but I don't know how to use the NOW() with it. All of the variables (letter, date) and a select query have been initialised within java using SparqlBuilder.

Comment: Why do you have `FILTER(?date > NOW() && }  ` and not just `FILTER(?date > NOW())}`?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you elaborated on what error you're getting with your current method.

Comment: filter functions take expressions, you should have a look at section 5 in https://rdf4j.org/documentation/tutorials/sparqlbuilder/ - maybe, `now()` isn't among the existing expressions, if not it should be among the functions, see `SparqlFunction` enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the RDF4J SparqlBuilder, functions are created using `org.eclipse.rdf4j.sparqlbuilder.constraint.Expressions` static methods. For example, to create the `BNode()` function, you just do this:

```java
Expression bnodeFunc = Expressions.bnode();
```

Similarly, for the `COUNT` aggregate function:

```java
Expression countAgg = Expressions.count(letter);
```

and to use that in your SELECT clause, you'd do something like this:

```java
Variable count = SparqlBuilder.var("count");
Projection select = SparqlBuilder.select(countAgg.as(count));
```

As for the `now()` function: Annoyingly, the list of function factory methods in `Expressions` is incomplete: for `now()` there is no direct static factory method. However, you can use the general `Expressions.function` method to create it, as follows:

```java
Expression nowFunc = Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.NOW);
```

By the way, your current graph pattern can be simplified quite a bit. Instead of this:

```java
GraphPattern longPattern = GraphPatterns.tp(letter, default.iri("a"), default.iri("Letter")).
                and(GraphPatterns.tp(letter, default.iri("writtenBy"), legislate.iri("John"))).
                and(GraphPatterns.tp(letter, legislate.iri("writtenOn"), date));
```

Do this:

```java
TriplePattern longPattern = letter.isA(ex.iri("Letter"))
        .andHas(ex.iri("writtenBy"), legislate.iri("John"))
        .andHas(legislate.iri("writtenOn"), date);
```

This is easier to read and shorter, and secondly, your use of `default.iri("a")` was incorrect (as an aside I don't even know how you have a Java variable called `default` because that's a reserved keyword and should result in a compilation error - so I've replaced with `ex` here).

Putting it all together you'd get something like this:

```java
SelectQuery select = Queries.SELECT()
        .prefix(ex)
        .prefix(legislate)
        .select(countAgg.as(count))
        .where(GraphPatterns.and(longPattern)
                .filter(Expressions.gt(date, nowFunc)));
```